# Extracting URL from address bar of a browser using JAVA

Tags: java, html

I am working on a sentiment analysis project. I am extracting data(product reviews) from a given product URL using JAVA while the user selects the product by navigating through the site. I need to fetch the URL from the address bar of the browser and pass it to my JAVA code. How can I extract the URL ? How do I link the two codes ? I am already using jsoup library in my java code for extracting reviews from a link that the user specifies from console in eclipse. Is there any way such that the user is just supposed to select the product and it automatically fetches the URL from address bar? Here is my JAVA code for extracting reviews.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class dataextraction {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Document doc;
    try {
            String link;
            System.out.println("Enter the link of the product to be reviewed");
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 

            link=in.readLine(); 


            // need http protocol
            doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();


            // get page title
            String title = doc.title();
            System.out.println("title : " + title);

            Elements p= doc.select("p.line.bmargin10");
            //get all links
            String text = p.text();
            System.out.println("text : " + text);

            BufferedWriter writer = null;
            try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("E:/output.txt"));
            writer.write(text);
                } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
                }
            finally {
            if (writer != null) {
                try {
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println(e);
                }
            }
        }       


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e);
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to extract URL of browser using java ??

Comment: Ya it would do. I just need to extract the URL and pass it to JAVA code.

Comment: please post code to fetch data so people can help you

Comment: Is your java code running in an applet, in a separate process, on the web server...?

Comment: I am extremely sorry for the inconvenience. I edited my question and added the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods.

**Extracting on click of a product**

Ok. may be this will help. Probably your jsp will use a hyperlink for all products. So use jquery to bind an onlcik function to all product href. If the url given is a relative path then you can use the HttpServletRequest's getRequestURL() to get the full path. So the script would be like..

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var relativeUrl = $(this).attr("href");
    var completeLink = "<%= request.getRequestURL() %>" + relativeUrl;

    // you can now pass completeLink to your java program via ajax to get the output

    //If you want to prevent browser from navigating to that url you could return false
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I am already using jsoup library in my java code for extracting reviews from a link that the user specifies from console in eclipse. Is there any way such that the user is just supposed to select the product and it automatically fetches the URL from address bar?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the full picture here. You want the user to browse through the eclipse url and when he click a particular link you need to get the address in the url for that link. Is that so?

Comment: The above code requires the user to select a product, copy the URL and then supply it to the JAVA code. So I want to know is there any way that doesn't require the user to copy the URL. Can it directly fetch the URL from the address bar of the browser and supply it to the JAVA code ?

Comment: In the above code if you manually provide a link of any product, then it extracts all the user reviews from that URL. I just need to automate the process i.e. it should automatically fetch the URL when the user selects any product.

Comment: Sorry to keep on asking questions, but what action should trigger the java program? I mean should you execute the program while clicking the link or are you going to click the link and then manually run the java program to get the url?

Comment: I am so sorry. See I have an application(a front end) using which the user will select URL & my above data extraction java code will be embedded in my Html code i.e. JSP file. So it needs to fetch the URL string, store it in a variable and that variable will be then used by my java code that is embedded inside my html code.

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope that helps.